# numpy refused to retrieve concatenated values

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, text-classification

numpy refused to retrieve concatenated values

> ```
> AraSent.split_train_validation_test(rating,0.2, 0.2,"unbalanced")   File "AraTweet.py", line 240, in split_train_validation_test
> test_ids = np.concatenate([review_ids_pos[0:ntest_pos] \ TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__method
> ```

after searching i have found that This is a numpy version problem. using version > 1.11.2, which doesn't support float index.
i have change them to np.int() but still the problem exist

```
test_ids = np.int(np.concatenate([review_ids_pos[0:ntest_pos] \
                       ,review_ids_neg[0:ntest_neg]\
                       ,review_ids_obj[0:ntest_obj]\
                       ,review_ids_neutral[0:ntest_neutral]]))
```

this the code

```
review_ids_pos=review_ids[rating=='POS']
review_ids_neg=review_ids[rating=='NEG']
review_ids_neutral=review_ids[rating=='NEUTRAL']
review_ids_obj=review_ids[rating=='OBJ']

np.random.shuffle(review_ids_pos)
np.random.shuffle(review_ids_neg)
np.random.shuffle(review_ids_neutral)
np.random.shuffle(review_ids_obj)

if balanced == "unbalanced":
ntest_pos = np.floor(len(review_ids_pos)*percent_test)
ntest_neg = np.floor(len(review_ids_neg)*percent_test)
ntest_neutral = np.floor(len(review_ids_neutral)*percent_test)
ntest_obj = np.floor(len(review_ids_obj)*percent_test)

nvalid_pos = np.floor(len(review_ids_pos) * percent_valid)
nvalid_neg = np.floor(len(review_ids_neg) * percent_valid)
nvalid_neutral = np.floor(len(review_ids_neutral) * percent_valid)
nvalid_obj = np.floor(len(review_ids_obj) * percent_valid)
validation_ids = np.concatenate([review_ids_pos[ntest_pos:ntest_pos+nvalid_pos] \
                       ,review_ids_neg[ntest_neg:ntest_neg+nvalid_neg]\
                       ,review_ids_obj[ntest_obj:ntest_obj+nvalid_obj]\
                       ,review_ids_neutral[ntest_neutral:ntest_neutral+nvalid_neutral]])

AraSent.split_train_validation_test(rating,0.2, 0.2,"unbalanced")
```

Comment: What is `ntest_pos`?  The error message refers to the 'slicing' step, not the concatenation.  This part: `review_ids_pos[0:ntest_pos]`.  It didn't even get to the `concatenate, much less 'retrieve values'.

Comment: @hpaulj i have updated my question, can you take a look again.

Comment: `np.floor` produces a float, e.g. `np.floor(12*.76)` => `9.0`.  `int(12*.76)` or `int(np.floor(...))` might work better.  Older versions of numpy tolerated float indices, but newer versions have tightened the accepted types.

Comment: thank you its worked with me